# DragDrop Event return the position in form and the drag and drop is in flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm dragging and dropping the pictureBox in FlowlayoutPanel but the event return the position in form...I need this position in FlowLayoutPanel(the pictureBoxes are in FlowLayoutPanel and are dragging and drop there)

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        flowLayoutPanel1.AllowDrop = true;
    }


    private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            picBox = (PictureBox)sender;
            if (picBox.Image != null)
            {
                var dragImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)picBox.Image, picBox.Size);
                IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
                Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
                DoDragDrop(picBox.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }


        void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    // Occurs when the user releases the mouse over the drop target 
    void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Posicao x " + e.Y + "Posicao Y " + e.Y);//reutrn the position in form, not in flowLayoutPanel
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use this method:

```
var point = flowLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

This translates screen position coordinates into control one, more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx).

Comment: Returns it the position that I dropped the pictureBox in flowLayoutPanel?

Comment: Yes it does as long as you drop item on `FlowLayoutPanel`.